# Web page : Display image from byte array

Tags: arrays, image, jsf, oracle-adf

I have an image `byte[]`, this `byte[]` is coming from LDAP [Oracle Open LDAP Authentication Provider] and I need to show this image into the page.

How can I do this?

Can I use `javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter` to write the `byte[]` or I should extract an instance of `java.io.OutputStream` from the `javax.faces.context.FacesContext` and write the `byte[]` into page.

If any one of these methods is possible, then I can might be able to create a custom JSF tag, to display the image, and try to execute the image creation in `encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)` method of the `javax.faces.render.Renderer`, where the `byte[]` will be send as attribute.

Can I use Servlet for this purpose? Actually I don't know whether or not I can call a Servlet from the `source` attribute of the `af:image`.

It will be very helpful to me if I get your suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an image byte[], this byte[] is coming from LDAP [Oracle Open LDAP Authentication Provider] and I need to show this image into the page.

You need to think of this at the HTTP level. The *page* doesn't contain the image (at least unless you're going to embed the data directly, which is almost always a bad idea for non-tiny images). It contains a *URL* to the image.

You should produce an `img` tag with an appropriate `href` which will allow you to fetch the data when the browser makes a request for it. That should almost certainly be a separate servlet, for simplicity - ideally responding to requests which include a "reasonable" filename (with a reasonable extension for the image).

At that point you fetch the data for the image and write it not to a `Writer` but to an `OutputStream` for the response, as it's binary data.

Comment: Thank you. What I understand is that create a custom tag->use writer to start img tag->add an href attribute with the url to the servlet->close the tag and in the doGet of that servlet write the image by using outputstream. Am I right?

Comment: @TapasBose: Yes, that's right. The href should *just* be enough information to fetch the data, e.g. put an ID within the URL. You shouldn't need to fetch the image itself as part of creating the page.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement it and will let you know.

Comment: can I pass an object as the request parameter to the servlet?

Comment: @TapasBose: It's not clear what you mean, but just think about it from the browser's point of view - all it will have is a URL.

Comment: I thought it might be possible to pass an object as the request param, but I am wrong. Since the request param creates a query string, how can I pass an object through it! I think it is not possible. So now I am thinking how can I pass the byte[] into the servlet which will be passed as the attribute to that custom tag. Should I store it in session? If I store it in session, then the architecture will not be generic. Can you suggest anything in this matter?

Comment: @TapasBose: No, you're thinking of it all wrong. Don't fetch the byte array at all when you're building the page - just put enough information to *fetch* the byte array (e.g. an ID) into the URL. Only do the fetch when the image itself is requested.

Comment: Yes that is possible to put an ID to the URL. But if I do so, then I perhaps need to make LDAP request twice. 

Actually, in scenario, I am displaying User Profile in a page where the information like name etc along with the image byte[] are coming from LDAP. I have a managed-bean where I process those information, set the values of the fields of that bean and display it in the page by using el-expression. If I set some Id then I think I will again have to invoke the LDAP request from that servlet. Isn't it?

Comment: @TapasBose: You may need to make two LDAP requests, but only one of them should need the actual image data, so the other one should be relatively cheap.